# Django - troubleshooting slow page load times for a comments page

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-templates, django-views

I have a page on my site that is dedicated to group comments. Users can create posts (i.e. questions or comments), and other users can comment on them. Comment hierarchy is identical to Facebook; there is no comment threading like reddit. Using Heroku.

I'm using django-debug-toolbar to optimize this page. Right now the page loads in 5-6 seconds; that's just the time that my browser waits for a response from the server (doesn't include JS/CSS/IMG load times). There are 30 SQL queries take between 80-100ms to load (am using prefetch_related on relevant m2m fields). The size of the page returned is 344KB, so not a monster page at all. The comments are paginated and I'm only returning 10 posts + all comments (in test each post only has 3-4 comments).

I can't figure out why it takes such a long time to load the page when the SQL queries are only taking up to 100ms to complete.

Below is the relevant code. I am getting back the 'posts' object and using a for loop to render each object. Within that 'posts' for loop I'm doing another for loop for the 'comments'.

What else can I do to further optimize this/reduce page load time?

```
# views.py
def group_app(request, course_slug):

    # get the group & plan objects
    group = Group.objects.get(slug=course_slug)

    # load the page with a new Post and comment form
    group_post_form = newGroupPost()
    post_comment_form = newPostComment(auto_id=False)

    # gather all the Posts that have already been created
    group_posts = GroupPost.objects.filter(group=group).prefetch_related('comments', 'member', 'group')

    paginator = Paginator(group_posts, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page = 1
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'group': group,
        'group_post_form': group_post_form,
        'posts': posts,
        'next_page': int(page) + 1,
        'has_next': posts.has_next(),
        'post_comment_form': post_comment_form
    })
    if request.is_ajax():
        return render_to_response('group-post.html', variables)
    else:
        return render_to_response('group-app.html', variables)


# group-app.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block canvas %}

    <div id="group-body" class="span8">

        {% include "group-body.html" %}

     </div>
{% endblock canvas %}


# group-body.html
{% for post in posts %}

    {% include 'group-post-item.html' %}

{% endfor %}


# group-post-item.html
{% with post_avatar=post.member.get_profile.medium_image.url %}

<div class="groupPost" id="{{ post.id }}">

    <div class="avatarContainer">
        {% if post_avatar %}
            <img class="memberAvatar" src="{{ post_avatar }}" alt="">
        {% else %}
            <img class="memberAvatar" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/generic-avatar.png">
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="postContents">

        <div class="groupPostComment">

            <h6 class="comment-header">SHOW/ADD COMMENTS</h6>

            <div class="comments">
                {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                    {% with comment_avatar=comment.member.get_profile.medium_image.url %}
                    <div class="commentText">
                        <p class="comment-p">{{ comment.comment }}</p>
                    </div>
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endwith %}
```

Comment: It might be related to avatar. What are you using for it? Also are you using remote storages like S3?

Comment: Django debug toolbar is very useful to analyse SQL queries, but I've found it can significantly slow down page loads. Does the page still load slowly if you disable the debug toolbar?

Comment: @neokya, ha - just disabled all avatar/image related calls and the page is returning in a little over 1-2s (I'm in Singapore and using us-east Heroku). I am using django-storages/S3. So I guess the question now is, how to get profile images without it bogging down the page load. Alasdair - you're right, it does slow down the full page load. But it seems in this case that the django-storages/S3 load is a bigger culprit.

Comment: ah I got you there, what are you using for avatar? User uploads avatar or you create thumbnail from uploaded image?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this is related to avatar image and not SQL queries. Working with remote storages like S3 is a bit slow. But it should not hamper the user experience as you have faced above.

I didn't get what you are using to get 'avatar' image, but I would suggest to use some third party packages like.

1. [Easy_thumbnails](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - It is really nice and has lots of options. I recently shifted to this you. In case of remote storages, you could pregenerate avatars with celery and serve saved thumbnail
2. [sorl-thumbnail](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - I used this for my previous project. It doesn't have option to pregenerate, so first request is slow. But once thumbnail is created, next request will be fast. It has smart caching. I tried to fork it here to use with celery https://github.com/neokya/sorl-thumbnail-async

I hope it helps.